# Copy Merge fIelds From one word document to another in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word

I'm editing a vb.net app for a mate and part of the requirements are to copy merge fields from one word document to another. I can copy them across using document.content.text but they come out as text (should've figured this i guess).

I think i've got them selected by:

```
Dim tDocFields As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Fields
tDocFields = tDocument.Content.Fields
```

I'm then activating the doc i want to copy into and i think i need to then copy into that doc using the related word app.

```
vDocument.Activate()
vWord.Selection. ??? Insert() ???
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated... Am i on the right lines even?

Comment: I need to solve a similar problem. Did you find a solution and if so, can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the available fields via the `Fields` collection however it has all the fields not just merge fields. You can easily identify merge fields but will have to do some basic parsing to extract the field name. The following code shows a messagebox with the contents of each merge field in a document:

```
Dim lo_field As Field
Dim lo_range As Range
Dim lo_fieldText As String

For Each lo_field In mo_doc.Fields
    If lo_field.Type = WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField Then

        lo_range = lo_field.Code()

        lo_fieldText = lo_range.Text
        MsgBox(lo_fieldText)

    End If
Next
```

Once you've found each of the merge fields you can create new merge fields in the new document like so:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

    Dim mo_doc As Document
    Dim mo_missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' Open word
        Dim lo_word As New Application
        lo_word.Visible = True

        ' Create a new word document
        mo_doc = lo_word.Documents.Add(mo_missing, mo_missing, mo_missing, mo_missing)
        mo_doc.Activate()

        ' Add a merge field
        mo_doc.Fields.Add(lo_word.Selection.Range, WdFieldType.wdFieldMergeField, "mergefieldname", True)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: VB.NET has named and optional parameters, so you'd never need the mo_missing object when working with Word's object model!

Comment: This copies the fields, but not any of the formatting.  Is there a way to get the formatting around the fields as well?  The only way I've found to do it so far is to copy and paste through the clipboard which is slow and feels wrong.  I've tried setting targetApp.Selection.FormattedText = sourceRange.Code.FormattedText but they're incompatible types for me at run time.